# I can not run my project on iphone

Tags: xamarin

always when I run my project direct on iphone the following error occurs
[image]

What can be the cause since error, I use visual studio 2017 and xamarin is updated, xcode in mac is updated. I can not identify, does anyone know the solution?

Comment: That does not look like an error to me. Have you tried doing what it suggests?

Comment: You need to sign your app with a developer provisioning profile - which is exactly what the message is telling you.

Comment: I already did this procedure

Comment: I created the provisioning, I downloaded, import the xcode item into devices

Comment: do you have VS set to use the correct profile when building and deploying?

Comment: I do not know what really happened but I just rebooted my computer and it worked,